# org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: ;

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails from my springboot application and getting the following error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: ;
  nested exception is:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out] with root cause
```

This is what my properties file looks like

application.properties

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connecttimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.host=smtp.office365.com
spring.mail.password=<passwordhere>
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=kshitij_kohli@intuit.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smpt.auth=true
```

EmailSender.java

```
package com.intuit.utils;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.MessagingException;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

@Service
public class EmailSender {

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String from;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void sendMail(String to) throws MessagingException, javax.mail.MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper;
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);//true indicates multipart message

        helper.setFrom(from);

        String subject = "some subbject";

        String body = "some body";


        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setText(body, true);//true indicates body is html
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Some authentication I am missing it seems. I have to send emails to the corporate accounts at my organization using the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the authentication is blocked by the organization and there are some org-specific steps needed for mails to go through - nothing wrong with the property file as such.